# Persistência de dados usando event sourcing

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, ddd, persistência

Recentemente eu ouvi falar sobre Event Soucring em um [vídeo do Greg Young](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHGkaShoyNs) e achei uma ideia que parece ser muito útil em vários sistemas nos quais ter um histórico dos dados é importante.

O que eu entendi é que ao invés de persistirmos o estado das entidades do sistema e atualizarmos conforme o estado muda, nós persistimos eventos, que correspondem às modificações de estado.

Pelo que eu entendi persistimos os eventos correspondentes a cada agregado presente no modelo de domínio, o que faz sentido, já que os agregados são tratados como um todo no domínio.

A minha única dúvida é: como alguém persiste eventos? Persistir estado já não é trivial em bancos relacionais, mas conseguimos lidar com isso mapeando propriedades para colunas de tabelas.

Por outro lado, não é claro para mim como persistir eventos na prática? Usamos bancos relacionais mesmo, ou temos de usar um tipo diferente de banco específico para isso?

A única coisa que eu pensei seria ter um banco relacional, com uma tabela para cada evento de cada agregado. Então se um agregado é `Pedido` representando um pedido, teriamos tabelas `PedidoCriado`, `PedidoAlterado`, `PedidoCancelado` com os dados referentes ao evento.

Mas isso não me parece o jeito certo, porque parece que pode virar uma confusão com o tempo. Além disso, ao alterar um pedido, muitas propriedades ficam iguais. Se a ideia é salvar só os deltas, só o evento em si, muitas colunas ficariam em branco.

Enfim, se eu quiser usar Event Sourcing e persistir os eventos ao invés de persistir o estado, como eu devo persistir esses eventos? Qual é o mecanismo correto para fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

O tipo de banco de dados que você usa para implementar o Event Sourcing é indiferente. Creio que nisso resida o fato da dúvida sobre esse tema: não é sobre aplicar ferramentas diferentes para solucionar novos problemas mas sim enxergar velhos problemas de maneira diferente e modelá-los de maneira diferente. Isso independe da ferramenta utilizada.

Apesar do hype recente, a idéia do Event Sourcing não é nova. Ela já existia em 2000 e foi publicada em 2005 pelo Martin Fowler: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html

O site dele explica muito bem a concepção da idéia:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurando na internet eu também vi esta apresentação aonde, na prática, explica bem os problemas e as vantagens do Event Sourcing e faz esse paralelo entre eventos e mapeamento de objetos relacionais.

https://ookami86.github.io/event-sourcing-in-practice/

Espero que ajude!